# How are these labels being generated?

Tags: arcgis-pro

[image]I am trying to edit these labels and I don't see how they are displaying their numbers. The dimension that is shown is not anywhere in the attribute table. I am using ArcGIS  Pro 2.8.[image]

Here is the contents panel

[image]

Comment: Maybe they are [annotations](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/annotation/annotation.htm)?

Comment: You seem to have several table with "label" in their name and have certainly several different type of label displayed. It's not clear witch label you are referring to but the visible table use the "FID_Addr_Final" field for labelling and there certainly is some label that could have came from that field....

Comment: They could be dimensions, graphics or annotations. You need to edit you question and show the source of the layer. If there is no layer that turns them on/off it would suggest they are graphics in the map.

Comment: If you go to the properties of that layer and then into Source is Feature type Dimension? If not, what is it? If it is simple then they are likely labels

Comment: Hornbydd may well be right about the numbers being dimensions. Selecting a dimension highlights the number the way seen in your screenshots, which is different from the highlighting on a selected geometry layer. from I've added a section to my answer about how to check if they are dimensions and find what property they're displaying. It's been some time since you asked this question, so if this was the problem I hope it hasn't been holding you up.

Answer (score 5):

## 1 - Check which layer the label is on

It's easy for a label to be coming from some layer you didn't expect. Switch layers on and off until you are sure you know which layer has the label that interests you.

As J.R says in the comments, the "label" may even be an annotation.

## 2 - Look at the layer label settings

You have the correct pane open on the right, so once you find the layer this should help you.

## 3 - Cycle through the different label classes

ArcGIS Pro allows multiple labels on a layer! Find the "Class" tab and click on the little ▼ arrow on its right to see them. Select each of these to see them.

[image: Screenshot of dropdown labelled 'Class' open to show three different classes]

## 4 - Check the Expressions

Under the "Expression" heading, there will be a small block of code, in one of the languages ArcGIS Pro supports. Usually this will be just a field name from the feature, but it is possible for the Expression to involve multiple fields and function calls.

The label you are interested contains dashes (-) at each end. These *may* be part of the field value, but they are more likely to be concatenated to the field value in the labeling Expression so look out for them.

## 5 - Dimension Features (Added 18th February 2022)

As Hornbydd suggests in the comments, these could be [Dimension Features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/dimensions/dimensions-in-arcgis-pro.htm). Once you identify the layer, through the steps above, right-click on it, select "Properties" and "Source", then look at the "Feature Type".

[image: Dialog box labelled 'Layer Properties' with 'Source' selected from list on the left and a table showing 'Feature Type' is 'Dimension'.]

You will also find that the Attribute Table for Dimensions will be full of properties like `DIMENSION TYPE`, `EXTENSION ANGLE` and `STYLE ID`, as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: ArcGIS Pro screenshot showing Dimension feature selected and Attribute Table full of Dimension Properties. On the right is the 'Label Class' pane, empty except for the message Select a feature layer in the Contents pane.]

What this doesn't have is offer you any Labeling Properties. So where can you change the font, or colors, or text?

Dig through the documentation on [Dimension Styles](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/dimensions/dimension-styles.htm) and you'll find that you do it in the **Catalog**. Right-click on the dimension features, and select 'Dimension Feature Class Properties'. You can't edit an existing style here. You can only view settings or copy them. But this will allow you to see where it is pulling from. In particular, the dashes appearing on some of the numbers may be added with the "Add prefix and/or suffix" option.

[image: Screenshot of Feature Class Properties pane with red box drawn around 'Expression' set to 'Add prefix and/or suffix' while 'Prefix' and 'Suffix' are set to a single dash.]

## Screenshot Request (Added 11th February 2022)

Can you post a screenshot that includes your **Contents** pane (it's usually on the left), with all layers disabled except the one with your problem labels? Make sure that you have selected the remaining visible layer so we know which Labeling settings we are seeing. Like this:

[image: Screenshot of ArcGIS Pro with the layer all layers except 'cfev_karst_statewide' hidden, and that layer selected an its Attribute Table displayed]

However, I see something different when I do this. When you select a feature, you see its *label highlighted in cyan*. I have not managed to make this happen, even if I switch off all other Symbology. So the numbers you are seeing may be coming from somewhere *other* than the usual Label settings.

[image: Screenshot of ArcGIS Pro with all Symbology disabled]

You may get some additional information if you select the "List by Labeling" tab in the Contents:

[image: Screenshot of ArcGIS Pro with the 'List by Labeling' tab selected in the Contents]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The labels are their own layer. There is only one drop down in the class drop down. I think I have the expressions screenshotted in the main post, but that field in the table is not the same as what the label is displaying. I have no idea where the numbers being displayed are coming from and just need to figure out how to edit them. I'll put more screenshots in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my answer with still more things to check. But there is something curious about how ArcGIS displays you selection, as noted.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the contents panel

Comment: Sorry, but what would be most useful is one screenshot that shows these four things: 1. Contents pane with only one layer visible, and that layer selected, 2. Map showing that the labels which concern you still visible, 3. Labels pane with the Expression for your selected layer, 4. Attributes Table for the selected layer. It doesn't matter if this shrinks down too small to read, we can click on the picture to open it in full screen.